# How to EXTRACT from long string by SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

By using Bigquery SQL (#standardSQL) , I want to extract 0.1e1 and 0.55e6 to another column **and** convert data type float -> int64.

```
   \nsub_total:\n- !ruby/object:BigDecimal 18:0.1e1\n- !ruby/object:BigDecimal 18:0.55e6\ninvoice_number:\n- \n- '
```

My expected:

String | 1 | 550000

Comment: Based on what rules ***exactly***?  Is the rest of the string ***always*** and **exactly*** the same as shown?  If any of it can very, describe ***precisely*** what can and can not vary.

Comment: Thanks to @MatBailie, the rest of the string changes every time users update. I mean on the string above, it only the same when our users update the price. So I can say that the string always changes and it's not a fixed string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regexp_extract_all()` to extract the strings.  Then convert to a float and then to an integer to sum them:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(cast(cast(val as float64) as int64))
        from unnest(regexp_extract_all(str, '[0-9][.][0-9]*e[0-9]+')) val
       )
from (select '   \nsub_total:\n- !ruby/object:BigDecimal 18:0.1e1\n- !ruby/object:BigDecimal 18:0.55e6\ninvoice_number:\n- \n- ' as str
     ) t;
```

EDIT:

If you want to extract these into an array, just use:

```
select t.*,
       (select array_agg(cast(cast(val as float64) as int64))
        from unnest(regexp_extract_all(str, '[0-9][.][0-9]*e[0-9]+')) val
       ) as int_array
from (select '   \nsub_total:\n- !ruby/object:BigDecimal 18:0.1e1\n- !ruby/object:BigDecimal 18:0.55e6\ninvoice_number:\n- \n- ' as str
     ) t
```

If you want these in separate columns, just use array operations.

EDIT:

If you want the values in separate columns:

```
select t.*, ar[safe_ordinal(1)] as col1, 
       ar[safe_ordinal(2)] as col2
from (select t.*,
             array_agg(cast(cast(val as float64) as int64)) as ar
      from (select '   \nsub_total:\n- !ruby/object:BigDecimal 18:0.1e1\n- !ruby/object:BigDecimal 18:0.55e6\ninvoice_number:\n- \n- ' as str
           ) t
     ) t
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to sum the values, they want the two values in separate columns

Comment: Thanks all, @MatBailie is true, I want its in separate columns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gordon, it's fantastic. And could you guild me to separate 2 values (1 and 550000) into 2 separate columns?